# Does a method signature in declaration typescript include return types and paramter types (basically the type annotations)

Tags: typescript

Or is there a way to get the function return types and parameter types from declaration typescript file (d.ts) with method signature whose statements includes function return types and parameter types in type annotation. For example:

```
loadViewModel? (componentName: string, viewModelConfig: any, callback: (result: any) => void): void;
```

has void as function return type and string , any as parameter types.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: What I meant was how could i get the return types of functions that are there in declaration typescript files using typescript services library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I meant was how could i get the return types of functions that are there in declaration typescript files using typescript services library.

There are a few steps to this:

- boiler plate : setup language services and use `getProgram`
- use the visitor for a source file to get `function` declarations. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/compiler/ast-tip-children.html
- For each found item get its associated type with the type checker: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/compiler/checker.html

## More

I've created an IDE to experiment with compiler ideas : http://alm.tools/